# Java class with its own reference as a generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

Some of my interface implementation methods need to return an object of the class interface. This is how I am trying to model the interface, but it seems wrong passing the same class type to itself:

```
interface Diff<T extends Diff> {
    T lessThan(T diff);
}

class ADiff implements Diff<ADiff> {
    @Override
    public ADiff lessThan(ADiff other) {
        return new ADiff();
    }
}

class BDiff implements Diff<BDiff> {
    @Override
    public BDiff lessThan(BDiff other) {
        return new BDiff();
    }
}
```

If I don't use generics, this is what I would need to do:

```
interface Diff2{
    Diff2 lessThan(Diff2 diff2);
}
class ADiff2 implements Diff2{
    @Override
    public Diff2 lessThan(Diff2 diff2) {
        if(diff2 instanceof ADiff2)  //I want to avoid these checks
            return (ADiff2) diff2;
        else throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite a common pattern. But the signature should be `Diff<T extends Diff<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I am actually facing a big issue migrating this code to Kotlin, it's not happy with nesting generics.

Comment: This is basically the same thing `Comparable` does.

Comment: `Enum` does it too.

Comment: @user2357112: It's not the same as `Comparable`. `Comparable` doesn't have any methods that return a `T`; and `Comparable`'s type parameter doesn't have any bounds.